# Error installing packages on R 3.1.2

Tags: r

I have just installed R and I just came up with this error on the first time I ran R:

Error installing package: Erro: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library'

How can I fix this?

Comment: Two choices: get permissions or set up a library in a directory for which you have write access. Search on `.libPaths` for specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 4.2 in the FAQ's gives [the solution](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#I-don_0027t-have-permission-to-write-to-the-R_002d3_002e1_002e2_005clibrary-directory).

My preference is to create a .Renviron file in my Working Directory, and add a line to it containing:

```html
R_LIBS=C:/working/RS
```

Your Working Directory is set on the menu at:

```html
Tools -> Global Options -> Default working directory (when not in a project):
```